# How to find EC2 availability zone that's closest to a specific website

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, cloud, ping

I want to find the EC2 availability zone (e.g. eu-central-1) that's closest to a single specific website (e.g., www.stackoverflow.com).

In theory I can achieve this by manually starting up an instance in each availability zone, and doing ping to the website from inside `ssh`. However this is too cumbersome and expensive. Is there an automated way to do this?

I know of services [1][2] that allow you do to this when using your own IP address, but none that allows the use of a specific other website (e.g. www.stackoverflow.com).

[1] https://cloudharmony.com/speedtest#for-aws

[2] https://ping.psa.fun/

Comment: `eu-central-1` is a region, not an availability zone. Also, it would help if you could describe more exactly what you are trying to accomplish. For example AWS Route53 Latency Based Routing may be exactly what you need, but I don't know what your end goal is.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be specific on what is exact use case?

Btw, The naming mapping is here in doc and an AZ should provide you same latency and availability.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html